# Jquery read <?php echo get_option('value'); ?> and not the value

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, echo

This is the php function present in function.php :

```
<?php
add_action('admin_menu', 'baw_create_menu');
function baw_create_menu() {
    add_menu_page('Bubbles', 'Bubbles', 'administrator', __FILE__, 'baw_settings_page');
    add_action( 'admin_init', 'register_mysettings' );
}
function register_mysettings() {
    register_setting( 'baw-settings-group', 'category' );
}
function baw_settings_page() {
?>
<div class="wrap">
<form method="post" action="options.php">
    <?php settings_fields( 'baw-settings-group' ); ?>
    <?php do_settings_sections( 'baw-settings-group' ); ?>
    <textarea style="width:400px" name="category"><?php echo get_option('category'); ?></textarea>

    <?php submit_button(); ?>
</form>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

And I want to get the string :

```
  var category = "<?php echo get_option('category'); ?>";
  alert(category);
```

But the alert gives me my php code: `<php echo get_option ('category');?>` And not the string such as "banana"

Comment: Not sure what you are asking, can you show some code?

Comment: "*and not the value*" means what exactly?

Comment: I'm sorry, but your English isn't very good. Could you please post some code examples alongside what you want to accomplish?

Comment: Ok, so I udapte my post !

Comment: Is the `var category = ...` snippet in a .js file?

Comment: @JasonP yeah ! But the same if I put directly in the header

Comment: Doesn't matter, PHP can't be parsed in a JS file.

Comment: don't directly echo php data into a JS content. you should ALWAYS use json_encode() for that, to guarantee you're outputting syntactically valid JS. The slightest error in PHP could cause a JS syntax error and kill the whole script block.

Comment: Ok, thank's all of you !!!! :-)

Comment: Wait, so did you move your category variable from your .js file to your .php file?

Comment: @NobleUplift Yes but how?

Comment: Didn't you say you put it in the header of your .php file? Inside of a `<script>` tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var category = <?php echo json_encode(get_option('bulle_index_1')); ?> ;
alert( category );
```

http://www.php.net/json_encode

Answer (score 0):

PHP cannot be parsed in a .js file. You need to create a function in your .js file and pass in the string returned from PHP:

```
function fromPHP(phpString) {
    var category = phpString;
    alert(category);
}
```

In your .php file:

```
fromPHP(<?php echo json_encode(get_option('bulle_index_1')); ?>);
```

Comment: @RokoCBuljan I tested json_encode in a local PHP shell and it does indeed work for this.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Read also @MarcB's comment on OP's question.

Comment: I missed the OP's response to @JasonP where he said that he put the two lines in the header of his PHP file. I must've read it before he edited it.